# asyncio.run() cannot be called from an event loop

Tags: python, python-requests, request, discord.py

I'm trying to call a function in async function and the problem is `asyncio.run()` don't work in a loop event

**Here is the RuntimeError:**

> asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop.

I also tried to use `nest_asyncio.apply()` but it's show me the same problem

**Here is my code:**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.content.startswith("!shodan organization"):
        ip = (message.content.split()[2])
        queryexec =  asyncio.run(query(hostname,apikey,ip))
      
        message.channel.send(queryexec)
```

**The function that I'm trying to call:**

```
async def query(hostname,apikey,ip):
        url = "http://%s" % (hostname) + "/ip/%s" % ip + "?key=%s" % apikey
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.NOT_FOUND:
            return 'test 1'
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
            return r.json()
```

Comment: If you are trying to send non-blocking requests, check [How do I make a web request?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=requests#how-do-i-make-a-web-request)

Comment: I recommend using [https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/] instead of `requests` as then it will be asynchronous so you would not need to use `asyncio.run`.

Comment: You can use `bot.loop.run_in_executor()` to run the blocking request.